# Type 'Object' provides no match for the signature '(artistsongs: string): string'.ts(2322)

Tags: ionic-framework

```
artistSelected(item: any) {
    console.log(item.artist);
    this.songsServices.getSongsListArtist(item.artist).subscribe(
      result => {
        this.songsServices.artistList = result;
        this.route.navigate(['./artistsongs']);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('There is an error');
      }
    );
  }

Service 

getSongsListArtist(album: string) {
        const completeUrl = `${environment.API_URL}?album=${album}`;
        return this.httpClient.get(encodeURI(completeUrl));
    }
    artistList(artistsongs: string) {
        return artistsongs;
    }
```

I am facing an error in this. Please sole me how to pass the object from one ts file to another ts file by using service.

Answer (score 0):

```
artistList(artistsongs: string) {
        return artistsongs;
    }
```

**change to**:

```
artistList(artistsongs: any) {
        return artistsongs;
    }
```

As i understand when you call `getSongsListArtist` it will return an array object or an object not a string only. You can use `typeof()` to check `this.httpClient.get(encodeURI(completeUrl))` return what kind of type.

Comment: error TS2322: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type '(artistsongs: any) => any

Comment: songsServices.artistList what type of this variable you assign in service file